# Changing the way '' is displayed in a code listing

Tags: listings

I'm writing some technical documentation with Latex, and as part of that I need to include a SQL query that can be copied and pasted into SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) from the document.

I've set up the listing package, and this works fine, however, on testing the document is displaying the ' character in a format that SSMS doesn't recognise, so it throws an error when trying to run the code.

The document is displaying them like this:

[image]

When it needs to be displayed like this

```sql
(t2.ext_ref , '')
```

I can get around this by copying the code into SSMS and then doing a find and replace, but this isn't great and someone else following the guide may get stumped by an unexpected error.

Is there a way to change how the ' is displayed in the document, or is there another package that I could use?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `upquote=true`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, upquote=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=SQL]
  (t2.ext_ref , '')
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be something simple I missed in the set up.